# Syncing cell phone with Banshee via Bluetooth

Tags: sync, banshee, bluetooth, mp3-player

Is it possible that if I connect my cell phone via Bluetooth with my laptop it appears like a mp3-player in Banshee so I can sync podcasts easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the brand and model of your phone.  If you can treat your phone as a USB Mass Storage Device, then there's a chance Banshee will be able to support it out of the box.  If your phone doesn't work, you can always [submit a bug report to the Banshee team](http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/) requesting support for your specific phone.  See the Hardware section on [Banshee's FAQ page](http://banshee.fm/support/faq/) for more information about which devices are currently supported.

Comment: I have tried this, even though my phone connects as a mass storage through bluetooth but still bashee, rhythmbox or any other music player won't recognize it, but when connect using the data cable, it works fine. Tried on different phones.

Comment: When the devices are connected via bluetooth, can you see them in the file browser? My computer doesn't have bluetooth so I haven't really played around with this. It's possible that Banshee and Rhythmbox are listening only for USB connections. Almost nothing shows up in Banshee's bug tracker relating to bluetooth, so it might not hurt to ask about it on their mailing list or report a bug.